# Setting Up the Licensing Verification Library on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, build.gradle, google-license-manager

im'triyng to implement the Google Licensing Verification in a Android Studio made app.
By following this lines: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html seems tath:

> As an alternative to adding the LVL as a library project, you can copy the library sources directly into your application. To do so, copy (or import) the LVL's library/src/com directory into your application's src/ directory.

I've done this but the import of:

```
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
```

fail..
Searching on google i've been noticed that i need to modify the build.grade file on my project, but i can't find a specific solution.

How can I reference the LVL in my android studio project?
There is some tutorial or example?

Thanks
Lorenzo

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I've got the solution!
You have to put the `library/src/com` directories in the `youroject/scr/main/java/com` and then click on the "Sync project with Gradle files" button.

Comment: That worked for me too. The official Android developer text:   "copy (or import) the LVL's library/src/com directory into your application's src/ directory."   isn't clear at all!

Comment: I combined this method with the one below, and was finally able to get it to recognize the library. Maybe we should start a kick starter for the Google documentation team, so they can hire a translator. lol Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you are compiling for the 23 API, you have to include ``useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`` in the android configuration: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Answer (score 54):

1. In Android Studio, Tools-Android-SDK Manager
2. In SDK Manager, in the extras section choose Google Play Licensing Library
3. Go back to Android Studio, and choose File-New-Import Module
4. ADK Manager will have put the downloaded files under your SDK directory, in my case `Desktop/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/play_licensing/library`
5. Choose to import this directory as a module, and give it a name. I used 'lvl'
6. Optionally change targetSdkVersion in the `lvl` module's `build.gradle` to match your project targetSdkVersion.
7. Then in your projects build.gradle, add the line `compile project(':lvl')` inside the `{dependencies{` section.
8. Re-sync Gradle and everything should compile correctly.

Comment: Also, you might want to change `targetSdkVersion` in the library's gradle script, so that it matches whatever version you are targeting for the app.

Comment: @NickFortescue what about the AIDL files?

Comment: android dev doc dint say step no. 7. Thanks Nick!

Comment: you can also copy the AIDL files into googlelicenselibrary\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\licensing

Answer (score 1):

step 6 is placed in
inside the `project(":android"){dependencies {` section.

Comment: Thanks, incorporated into my answer above.

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be added as a comment.

Comment: I didn't have enough rep to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the LVL sources to your application.
As an alternative to adding the LVL as a library project, you can copy the library sources directly into your application. To do so, copy (or import) the LVL's library/src/com directory into your application's src/ directory.
Visit:http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html